# Regular CW complex arising from a Morse decomposition

Tags: morse-theory, cw-complexes

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold equipped with a Morse function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb R$. It's been [shown](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2838) that $f$ gives rise to a CW decomposition *homeomorphic* to $M$ under the generic assumption that $(f,g)$ satisfies Morse-Smale transversality. What additional conditions does one need to impose in this situation to ensure that the CW complex is regular? (Regular means the attaching maps are homeomorphisms.)

It is true that every CW complex is *homotopy equivalent* to a simplicial complex, and those are all regular, but I'm asking for regularity on the nose.

(Note: I originally [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663344/regular-cw-complex-arising-from-a-morse-decomposition) the question on MSE.)

EDIT: I'm particularly interested in the case when Morse functions give rise to *pseudo-regular* CW complexes, by which I mean the incidence numbers of the cells all lie in $\{0,\pm 1\}$. By this definition, regular implies pseudo-regular, and pseudo-regular allows for a trivial boundary operator on the Morse-Smale complex.

Answer (score 8):

If the Morse function $f$ is perfect, then, for any choice of  metric $g$, the  attaching maps cannot be homeomorphism.  Indeed if the Morse function was perfect, then the boundary operator of the associated  Morse-Smale complex   is trivial.  If the attaching map  was a homeomorphism, then the boundary  operator cannot be zero. This can be seen from Thm. 4.5.1 of [these notes](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Morse2nd.pdf).

In any case, the ''attaching map'' has a rather nasty description which makes verifying that it is a homeomorphism is nearly impossible.

I might be able to be of more help if you explained  in more detail what would you do if you knew that the attaching maps are homeomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the question to clarify the situation I'm interested in.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$-perfect Morse functions are automatically pseudo-regular since all the incidence numbers  are $0$.  Functions with only even Morse indices are perfect. Moment maps of Hamiltonian $S^1$-actions are also perfect. The map $f: U(n)\to\mathbb{R}$ $T\mapsto {\rm Re}\;(AT)$, where $A$ is  a symmetric $n\times n$matrix with with simple, positive spectrum is also perfect.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned earlier today, a manifold like $S^2 \times S^2$ with a standard Morse function (giving one 0-cell, two 2-cells and one 4-cell) can never be regular for silly reasons -- the attaching map from the 4-cell is a map $S^3 \to S^2 \vee S^2$ which can't be an embedding for dimension reasons.

This example shows there's no hope for anything generic satisfying your embedding condition.  A minimal necessary condition would be for the k-skeleton to be locally k-dimensional, i.e. every point is in a closed k-cell.   I'm not certain if that is a strong enough condition, but its a start.